# New to IntelliJ IDEA, jest not finding test files

Tags: intellij-idea, jestjs

I am working on monorepo project using an nx and Angular. I am trying to run jest test and IntelliJ idea(with the green play button), but I’m in countering issue where jest is not finding any test files in the directory it’s looking at. The same test runs fine in VS code.

And here is the error message I’m getting

````
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
No files found in /Users/EEEE/Desktop/ABC/ABC.repo/apps/ABC
Make sure Jest's configuration does not exclude this directory.
To set up Jest, make sure a package.json file exists.
Jest Documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
...
(Repeat for each directory)
...
Process finished with exit code 1```
````

I’ve checked my jest configuration and it doesn’t seem to exclude the directory mentioned in the error message the directory do contain test files and a package.json file exist in in the root of my project. The test file followed the naming convention .spec.tsx .

I’m not sure why Jest is not finding the test files in IntelliJ idea. I have a hunch that the issue might be related to its configuration, but I’m not sure what additional configuration I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which IDE version do you use? What does your run configuration look like? Is it possible to provide a sample project where the issue can be reproduced?